# How to position divs bottom, in a footer?

Tags: html, css, footer

I want only the "social-content", and "company-address" divs to be constantly the bottom of page. I've tried position: fixed -> it worked some way. On my page you have to scroll down to see the content, and it was always visible, so that's why it didn't work.

footer:

```
  <footer>
    <div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="form-content">
            <form name="contactForm" method="post" action="index.php" >
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Describe the details..." required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <center><input type="submit" class="form-button" name="sendData" value="Send"></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="social-content">
                <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x" style="color:#000; padding: 0px 10px;"></i></a>

                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/EdgeTheCompany" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x" style="color:#000; padding: 0px 10px;"></i></a>

                <a href="https://twitter.com/EdgeTheCompany" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x" style="color:#000; padding: 0px 10px;"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <div class="company-address">
            <font size="4">
                Hungary<br/>
                Budapest<br/>
                Vörösmarty square 3.<br/>
                info@edge.one   </font>         
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer{
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(../img/mt3.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:top center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    text-align:left;
    color:#fff;

   }

.social-content{
    padding-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.company-address{
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: what exactly output r u expecting

Comment: I want the icons, and the information about the company, always to be on the bottom of the page, with any screen sizes.

Comment: try `position:absolute; bottom:0;` should make it stick

Comment: is there any content above footer if then show u r full code in jsbin or codepen or similar

Comment: if u want to use relative why not give margin-top in % ?